# Too many redirects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, https

I am working on a project and am trying to display a page in a browser using https server ----  https://moneytree.space/catalogs/traders
So far, I get the following:

[image]

If I just enter https://moneytree.space, the index.html from public directory is displayed. In my config/routes file, the root points to "catalogs/traders".

I need help with this. Here is my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default file:

Thank you.

Comment: this issue does not occur in development env right?

Comment: Yes, this issue didn't occur in development env.

Comment: What are you using for force ssl (ex: "config.force_ssl = tree" in config/production.rb) as I noticed that you're using DreamHost for your DNS?

Comment: yes, I use 'config.force_ssl = true'. Do you think this might be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to say based on the amount of data you provided, but...

My hunch is that you have an exception which redirects to the "500 oops!" page that generates an exeption that redirects to the "500 oops!" page that generates the exception that redirects to....

ending with a "too many redirects" error :)

Check out your error handling code and make sure everything is traced where you catch exceptions in around_filter blocks and such

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're redirecting to https for every request but not checking if it's already https?

```
$ curl -I http://moneytree.space/catalogs/traders
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Fri, 09 Oct 2015 17:41:08 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 193
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://moneytree.space/catalogs/traders
```

Comment: Everything is new to me, I need to understand what is really going on. Here are another check:                                                                          `curl -I https://moneytree.space
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Date: Fri, 09 Oct 2015 18:10:11 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 462
Last-Modified: Fri, 09 Oct 2015 12:01:15 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "5617ac8b-1ce"
Accept-Ranges: bytes`

Comment: You said:Perhaps you're redirecting to https for every request but not checking if it's already https? Where do I need to do these checks in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default file? I am novice in this, your help is very important.

Comment: it's probably somewhere in rails?

Comment: I use NetBeans IDE and when I run my rails app in production mode, no issues are raised. It works as it should be.